# ¿Cómo imprimir líneas en las que un carácter aparece al menos 8 veces?

Tags: linux, regex, bash, grep, gnu

En bash (GNU/Linux) tengo un fichero de texto y debo imprimir por pantalla aquellas líneas en las que se repita 8 o más veces un carácter específico, en mi caso la letra 'a'.

La opción más viable parece usar el comando `grep -E`, pero no termino de dar con la clave.

¿Alguien sabe cómo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una línea en la que haya al menos 8 `a`s será aquella formada por algo así como

```
.....a....a.....a.....a.....a.....a.....a....a...
```

Es decir, 8 apariciones de la letra `a` intercaladas entre ningún, uno o muchos caracteres.

Esto se puede representar fácilmente con la expresión:

```
(.*a){8}
```

Por lo que el comando que necesitas es:

```
grep -E '(.*a){8}' fichero
```

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
$ cat fichero
1
a1
a1a2
a1a2a3
a1a2a3a4
a1a2a3a4a5
a1a2a3a4a5a6
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9
```

Ejecutemos:

```
$ grep -E '(.*a){8}' fichero
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9
```

Alternativamente, puedes usar `awk`. Si definimos el delimitador como la letra `a` misma, lo que tendremos será tantos campos como apariciones de `a`... más uno. Es decir, una línea con ninguna `a` tendrá un campo; una con una aparición de `a`, tendrá dos campos; etc.

Por tanto, debemos seleccionar aquellas líneas que tengan al menos 9 campos:

```
$ awk -F'a' 'NF>8' fichero
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9
```

Alternativamente, también puedes convertir la cadena en una array, usando el hecho que `split()` devuelve el número de cachos que generó:

```
$ awk 'split($0, mi_array, "a")>8' fichero
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8
a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8a9
```

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente hay formas mejores, por ahora se me ocurre `awk` de la siguiente forma:

```
awk '{cnt=0;linea=$0;while (y=index(linea,"a")){cnt++;y++;linea=substr(linea,y)}if (cnt >= 8) print $0}' archivo
```

O a sugerencia de @fedorqui también de una forma más compacta

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FS="a"}{if (NF-1>=8) print $0}'
```

Comment: Si bien funciona, es bueno intentar utilizar las funcionalidades que ofrece `awk` de forma idiomática, como por ejemplo definir "a" como el separador de campos.

Comment: Si, de acuerdo, es más compacto y seguramente más óptimo, lo agrego..

Comment: `{if (NF-1>=8) print $0}` es correcto, pero es una forma muy poco idiomática de decir `awk 'NF>8' fichero`, como en mi respuesta. Una de las bellezas de `awk` es su capacidad de ser sucinto: `awk '/1/' fichero` es lo mismo que `awk '{if ($0 ~ /1/) {print $0}}' fichero`. [Lectura imprescindible](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/)